# Collector goes wrong | discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want people to be able to react to a message and then be contacted by the bot with 3 questions. The problem is that it skips all questions for its own and answers it for its own.

I would be happy if you can describe the problem to me well so that it no longer occurs. Here is my code:

```js
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
  if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
  if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();

  if (user.bot) return;

  if (reaction.message.channel.id === '809490905236373558') {
    if (reaction.emoji.name === '✅') {
      const questions = [`Test1`, `Test2`, `Test3`];
      const dmChannel = await reaction.message.guild.members.cache
        .get(user.id)
        .send('**Beantworte die Fragen du keks**');
      const collector = dmChannel.channel.createMessageCollector(() => true);
      let i = 0;
      const res = [];
      dmChannel.channel.send(questions[0]);
      collector.on('collect', async (msg) => {
        if (questions.length == i) return collector.stop('MAX');
        const answer = msg.content;
        res.push({ question: questions[i], answer });
        i++;
        if (questions.length == i) return collector.stop('MAX');
        else {
          dmChannel.channel.send(questions[i]);
        }
      });

      collector.on('end', async (collected, reason) => {
        if (reason == 'MAX') {
          const data = reaction.message.guild.channels.cache.find(
            (ch) =>
              ch.name.toLowerCase() == 'apply-final-bewerbungen' &&
              ch.type == 'text',
          );
          await data.send(
            `${reaction.message.member || reaction.message.author} (${
              reaction.message.author.tag
            }) hat eine Bewerbung abgegeben!\n\n${res
              .map((d) => `**${d.question}** \n ${d.answer}`)
              .join('\n\n')}`,
          );
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sends all questions without waiting because you don't check if the incoming message in your message collector is coming from the member. As the bot sends the first question, there is an incoming message your collector catches (the bot's message) and it sends the next ones till it reaches the end.

You can check if the `msg.author` is a bot in your `collector` and stop responding if it is. The following should work:

```js
collector.on('collect', async (msg) => {
  if (msg.author.bot) return;
  if (questions.length == i) return collector.stop('MAX');
```

Comment: Thank you but now here is another Problem, maybe you can have a look :)
I'm trying to get my bot to send a private message to a user where he can choose between 1 and 2, if he presses 1, a message comes up, but the problem is that he no longer answers and shuts down

Code:
https://starb.in/UMonUK.cs

Error:
https://imgur.com/hEAKshI